# JDBC driver cannot be loaded. Why? (Spring,Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jdbc

I have created a program (`SPRING`+`HIBERNATE`) through `Maven` two weeks ago and now it is having a problem with loading JDBC driver (which wasn't occur until now). So, my `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spring.hib</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibPav</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.27</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.7.Final </version>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

It seems that this file is clear. But what is the main problem that JDBC driver cannot be loaded while I am trying to create a `dataSource` bean.

Other files:

**datasource file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<bean
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>properties/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**properties file**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
jdbc.username=myinfuser
jdbc.password=myinfuserpw
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/database/datasource.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spring.dirba.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    ... 16 more
```

Anyone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get rid of the `;` at the end of your property

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
```

Spring uses reflection and the value of that property to load a `Class` instance by fully qualified class name. There is no class called `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;`. There is a class called `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, so use that.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. so reflection uses getClass() to retrieve a JDBC driver object?

Comment: @solvator Depends on the case. Here, I believe it uses `Class.forName(String)` or the overloaded version.

Answer (score 2):

did you add the postgres dependency in your pom.xml ??

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```