# Cannot load MySQL JDBC driver

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

Hi have a tomcat server with a web app in that is supposed to connect to a MySQL database.

The driver is loaded when I use `-verbose:class`

```
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from file:/app/tomcat/8.5.4/webapps/my-app/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar]
```

But for some reason it's still throwing me an exception when loading spring context:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>
> PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load class of driverClassName com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I tried to move the connector lib file to tomcat lib folder, but it didn't change anything. I tried different versions of the connector still same issue.

Comment: Where your tomcat folder located. Are you trying to run on development workstation or it crashes on web server after deployment? Do you use Eclipse IDE?

Comment: it's running on a Centos machine, not in eclipse. I created a folder in /app with all the things that i need. The permissions are alright.

Comment: Add the jar file to your system `classpath` instead!

Answer (score -1):

I can't find out what exactly problem is without your code files: but i can guess, due to this problems it throws this kinda Exception.

Possible solution, there's some mistake in database property file. 
This is some property, you can check, give database name and `username` `password` according to your system. The problem occurs due to single . or , or ; too.. You can find more detail [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887366/jdbc-driver-cannot-be-loaded-why-spring-hibernate)

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
jdbc.username=myinfuser
jdbc.password=myinfuserpw
```